# Is getResources().getIdentifier() method efficient enough to use it in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, drawable, android-resources

**Some information about the app:**

The app contains a lots of images in drawable folder.
The size of every image is between 1kb and 3kb. 
And I need to draw them into a ListView.

**What I need to get:**

I need store the identifier of the image (R.drawable.my_image) into database with some aditional user information.

**The problem:**

When I update the app (adding new image resources), the identifier may change. So, in database I will have an outdated identifier, which is linking to a non-existing resource.

I've thought to store the *resource name* in database instead of the *resource identifier* and them I will retrieve it by `getResources().getIdentifier(String, String, String)` method. But I don't know if this method is efficient enough to use it in a ListView. 
The documentation says `Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.`

Do you know any other solution?

Comment: use glide for memory management

Comment: @quicklearner im already using picasso for these pruporse. What I worry about, is the load time of getResources().getIdentifier() methods

Comment: try using recycler view and read about loaders

Comment: it might help u

Comment: @quicklearner thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Im using getResources().getIdentifier() method to load images into list (with recyclerview). My list has about 20 images. The average size is also less than 3kb. I've tried the app in older devices (wich behavior can be affected by his CPU) and it worked fine. I know this method is not recomended, but can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient to use it in a list view.

Official documentation of [Resources.getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method:

> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.

[**NOTE in documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know it. And I wrote it in the question. Do you have any solution for this?